# Always trigger custom follow-up intent

Tags: dialogflow-es

I have a (custom) follow-up intent that lets the user search through FAQ and returns the best match for the user's query. The intent has an entity (FAQQuery) assigned which should be matched to the "whole" user input.

How can I make sure that the follow-up intent is triggered for any user input? As of now the some phrases/words trigger other intents of my bot configuration.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a Followup Intent is probably not what you want to do, although using Contexts (which is what Followup Intents use) probably is the best route. To do this you can:

- In your message to the user where you prompt for the user's query, set an Outgoing Context (for example, you can call it "prompt").
- Create a Fallback Intent which accepts "prompt" as the Input Context.
- Use the entire text from the user in your fulfillment webhook.

Comment: I tried your solution by adding an output context 'feedback-user-always-prompt' to an intent and a follow-up fallback intent with input context 'feedback-user-always-prompt'. But in the simulator it will still match other intents.

Comment: @DaReal - It sounds like there may be some other reason its matching. I suggest you create a new question and post the Intents that you want to match, the Intents that are matching, and some example conversations (with screen shots in the simulator as well) that aren't working as you expect.